# Heyzap integration with unity "Configuration not present"

Tags: unity-game-engine, configuration, sdk, integration, heyzap

I have tried to integrate admob and unity ads on my unity game. However when I open `HeyzapAds.ShowMediationTestSuite();`
All networks are "off".

Admob displays:

- SDK Available
- Configuration not present
- SDK Started Successfully.

Unity displays:

- SDK Available
- Configuration not present
- SDK Failed to start.

I did all of the integration steps and am using Heyzap SDK version 10.